# In Android, why the startActivityForResult doesn't support SingleTask mode?

Tags: android

In my recent development, I found if a problem. For example, if there are two activities, says A and B, and the B is the SingleTask mode. If I use startActivityForResult(B) to start B Activity, and in the B, when I do

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

the result code cannot be delivered to the Activity A, but if I remove the SingleTask in the AndroidManifest.xml, the result code can be set.

Can anyone help to explain this please?

Answer (score 1):

`startActivityForResult()` does not work with `singleTask`, as explicitly said in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)).

Documentation explains:

> if the activity you are launching uses the singleTask launch mode, it will not run in your task and thus you will immediately receive a cancel result.

So the internal Android code seems to require the Activities to be in the same "task" to allow data to go back and forth.

Nothing you can do about it. Do not use `singleTask` with `startActivityForResult()`.